# SlackBot repeat the event without control

Tags: node.js, sockets, bots, slack

I am trying to create a bot in Slack called "Chochon", the problem is that when I receive the event "app_mention", chochon responds more than once several times in a row, instead of sending 1 message and stopping until they mention it again.

This is my code, chochon function:

```
    socketModeClient.on('app_mention', async ({ event }) => {
        try {
            console.log(event);
            let userBox = await Chochon.users.info({ user: event.user });
            let userProfile = userBox.user.profile;
            console.log(cli.green(`Event received : [ ${event.type} ] from [ ${userProfile.display_name} ]`));

            // Respond to the event
            Chochon.chat.postMessage({
                channel: event.channel,
                text: `Hello <@${event.user}>, I'm Chochon!, I'm a bot that can help you to manage your team.`
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
```

The slack client:

[image: Slack channel]

Full code:

```
// Dependencies :
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const cli = require('cli-color');

// Web client [CLI]
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/web-api');
const Chochon = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN.trim());  

// Socket IO
const { SocketModeClient } = require('@slack/socket-mode');
const appToken = process.env.SLACK_APP_TOKEN;
const socketModeClient = new SocketModeClient({ appToken });
socketModeClient.start();

// Internal functions
//const eventManager = require(path.resolve(__dirname, './utils/events/manager'));

socketModeClient.on('app_mention', async ({ event }) => {
    try {
        console.log(event);
        let userBox = await Chochon.users.info({ user: event.user });
        let userProfile = userBox.user.profile;
        console.log(cli.green(`Event received : [ ${event.type} ] from [ ${userProfile.display_name} ]`));

        // Respond to the event
        Chochon.chat.postMessage({
            channel: event.channel,
            text: `Hello <@${event.user}>, I'm Chochon!, I'm a bot that can help you to manage your team.`
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

socketModeClient.on('slash_commands', async ({ body, ack }) => {
    if (body.command === "/ping") {
        console.log(cli.green(`Event received : [ ${body.command} ]`));
        await ack({"text": "I got it, pong!"});
    }
});
```

Comment: If i put "once" instead of "on", Chochon work 1 time, but if i mention the bot again does not work :(

Comment: Are you sure that the line `socketModeClient.on('app_mention', …)` is only called once (so that you're not adding more than one listener)?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, i will show you the full function.

Comment: And the `Event received:` line is logged 4 times as well (and only for `app_mention`, not for the `/ping`)?

Comment: only for app_mention, /ping work perfectly

Comment: @robertklep I will put all code only in one function, let me update the question